# Remove whitespace left of li tags in nav breadcrumb

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a nav breadcrumb based on [Mozilla's nav demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

```css
nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.crumbs ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.crumb {
    display: inline-block;
}

.crumb a::after {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    content: '>';
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="crumbs">
    <ol>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes">Bikes</a></li>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes/bmx">BMX</a></li>
        <li class="crumb">Jump Bike 3000</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

I'm trying to remove the inserted "whitespace" that's to the left of the `Jump Bike 3000` (on the right side of the `>`).  I can see the issue in both Firefox and Chrome.  In Firefox's inspect element, it actually shows this as `whitespace` in the DOM:
[image]

Is there any way to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove **li** `inline-block` and add `display:flex` to `ol`

```
.crumbs ol {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```css
nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.crumbs ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.crumb {
    display: inline-block;
}

.crumb a::after {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    content: '>';
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    
}
```

```html
<nav class="crumbs">
    <ol>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes">Bikes</a></li>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes/bmx">BMX</a></li>
        <li class="crumb">Jump Bike 3000</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the literal whitespace between the elements in the markup will do it, but [Rayees AC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64032859/636077) is better.

```css
nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.crumbs ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.crumb {
    display: inline-block;
}

.crumb a::after {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    content: '>';
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="crumbs">
    <ol>
        <li class="crumb"><a href="bikes">Bikes</a></li><li class="crumb"><a href="bikes/bmx">BMX</a></li><li class="crumb">Jump Bike 3000</li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```